# FQL for users education and work info

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I tried to get the work and education of a public user. but it does not show anything even though i set permissions

```
user_education_history or friends_education_history permissions to view: hs_info, education_history, education
user_work_history or friends_work_history permissions to view: work_history, work
```

my FQl is

```
select education,name,work,hometown_location from user WHERE uid = 100004804171807
```

I checked it in Graph API Explorer with my access token

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible.

> **Permissions. To read the `user` table you need:**
>
> - **`no access_token`** for publicly available data: uid, name, first_name, middle_name, last_name, sex, locale, pic_small_with_logo,
>     pic_big_with_logo, pic_square_with_logo, pic_with_logo, username
> - `user_education_history` or `friends_education_history` permissions to view: hs_info, education_history, education
> - `user_work_history` or `friends_work_history` permissions to view: work_history, work
>
> *Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/*

According to the doc, work and education history of a user are not public. The `user_education_history`,  `friends_education_history`, `user_work_history`and `friends_work_history` permissions are only useful to retrieve the education/work history of the current user or his friends.

Comment: I think you did something wrong because it works on my side. What query have you tried? Update your initial post if needed.

Comment: I used the query `select education,name,work,hometown_location from user WHERE uid = 100004804171807` which is my friends user id. I run this in Graph API explorer - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=100004804171807%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname

Comment: Your link corresponds to a `Graph API` request whereas `SELECT ... FROM ... ` is an `FQL` query. Go to the [FQL query tab](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=select%20education%2Cname%2Cwork%2Chometown_location%20from%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20100004804171807).

Comment: yes in FQL tab i select the access token also but that gave `{
  "data": [
    {
      "education": [
      ],
      "name": "Mia Carmela Maravilla",
      "work": [
      ],
      "hometown_location": null
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Your friend perhaps [turned off his FB platform](https://www.facebook.com/help/211829542181913). Try with another friend.

Comment: Turning the platform off only disables API access to the information.

Comment: I could not understand. Please explain more

Comment: This is another subject, that's why I'm not giving much details about it. Turning the FB platform off, leads to a user being unable to be reached through the API. People do so when they don't want to be annoyed by apps. It is like they were unlinked from the apps / API platform. So, could you try with another friend (or several, until it works) and tell me the result?

Comment: Where i have to do FB platform off,

Comment: Read again what has been said.